# Why does statement keep repeating in this error checking code?

Tags: java

I'm trying to stop someone from entering a day number which is less than 0  and greater than 31. Its stuck in an infinite loop.

```
public void setDay(int setDayTo) throws IllegalArgumentException
            {   
                do
                {
                    if(setDayTo <= 0 || setDayTo >31)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Day is not in range from 1 to 31, please" + " " + 
                        "re-enter the date:");
                    }
                    // No Exception thrown
                    day = setDayTo;

                }while(day <= 0 || day > 31);   
            }
```

Comment: You are not throwing any exceptions - how do you expect `setDayTo` to ever change within this loop?

Comment: `day = setDayTo;` is always ran, regardless of the print statement. And you never re-prompt for new input

Comment: Any suggestions as to what i should do then?

Comment: should i remove the throws statement and the setDayTo statement?

Comment: Show a [mcve] for how you are running this method

Comment: Basically im taking user input in, i dont want them entering a invalid date. This method is contained in a Date class. The user puts in the date in another class. Ill post some code now

Comment: If you have a `throws`, then actually `throw new IllegalArgumentException`... Not just print

Comment: System.out.print("Enter the date the account opened: ");
  int d = keyboardIn.nextInt();
  dateOpened.setDay(d);
  System.out.print("Enter the month the account opened: ");
  int m = keyboardIn.nextInt();
  dateOpened.setMonth(m);
  System.out.print("Enter the year the account opened: ");
  int y = keyboardIn.nextInt();
  dateOpened.setYear(y);

Answer (score 2):

> Why does statement keep repeating in this error checking code?

Because you never accept new input and update the `setDayTo` value, and since you're using that unchanging value to set `day`, if the value is out-of-range to start with, it will be out-of-range forever.

Either have the method throw an exception (probably best, and probably without outputting anything; that would be the job of the code calling it), or have it accept a new value (again, though, that would probably be the job of the code calling it).

Comment: i need it to throw an exception and recover from it to ask the user again

Comment: How should i go about it?